# Split lines and create new dataframe

Tags: r

I have a file, file.txt, with data that looks like as follows,

```
<z:row ows_Req_Name1='John' ows_ReqPriority='High' ows_ReqDate='2012-10-10' />
<z:row ows_Req_Name1='Jack' ows_ReqPriority='Low' ows_ReqDate='2012-11-10' />
<z:row ows_Req_Name1='John' ows_ReqDate='2012-12-10' />
```

Not all lines contain all the required information. For eg., the last line above does not have  an entry for ReqPriority like the other lines. I split the data into a dataframe using,

```
data.frame(do.call(rbind,strsplit(readLines('file.txt'),'ows_',fixed=T)))
```

but due to the missing entries in some of the lines the dataframe does not come out properly.

Any suggestions on how I can export this into a df and fill in the missing values with NA.

```
Req_Name1   ReqPriority    ReqDate
John        High           2012-10-10
Jack        Low            2012-11-10
John        NA             2012-10-10
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to parse XML. Why not use a package (`XML`?) designed for that purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since each row looks a lot like how data.frames are created in R, I thought is would be fun to work it this way:

```
x <- readLines('file.txt')
x <- gsub("<z:row (.*) />", "data.frame(\\1)", x)
x <- gsub("ows_", "", x)
x <- gsub(" ", ", ", x)
x
# [1] "data.frame(Req_Name1='John', ReqPriority='High', ReqDate='2012-10-10')"
# [2] "data.frame(Req_Name1='Jack', ReqPriority='Low', ReqDate='2012-11-10')" 
# [3] "data.frame(Req_Name1='John', ReqDate='2012-12-10')"                    

library(plyr)
do.call(rbind.fill, lapply(x, function(z)eval(parse(text = z))))
#   Req_Name1 ReqPriority    ReqDate
# 1      John        High 2012-10-10
# 2      Jack         Low 2012-11-10
# 3      John        <NA> 2012-12-10
```

But it should come with the usual warnings about using `eval/parse`.

Answer (score 2):

flodel's response is better but I got to playing and used some regex (I'm a bit rusty with regex right now so this was good):

Read in yuor data:

```
x <- readLines(n=3)
<z:row ows_Req_Name1='John' ows_ReqPriority='High' ows_ReqDate='2012-10-10' />
<z:row ows_Req_Name1='Jack' ows_ReqPriority='Low' ows_ReqDate='2012-11-10' />
<z:row ows_Req_Name1='John' ows_ReqDate='2012-12-10' />
```

Reconstructing the data:

```
new <- lapply(strsplit(x, " ows_| />"), "[", -1)
new <- lapply(new, function(x) gsub("'", "", x))
tester <- function(x){
   x[match(c("Req_", "ReqP", "ReqD"), substring(x, 1, 4))]
}
new2 <- lapply(lapply(new, tester), function(x){
    gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", gsub(".*=", " ", x))
})

DF <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, new2))
n <- lapply(lapply(new, tester), function(x){
     na.omit(gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", gsub("=.+.", " ", x)))
})
colnames(DF) <- n[[which.max(sapply(n, length))]]
DF
```

Outputs this:

```
  Req_Name1 ReqPriority    ReqDate
1      John        High 2012-10-10
2      Jack         Low 2012-11-10
3      John        <NA> 2012-12-10
```